# elif isinstance(cnfs, (type(None), str)): RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__

Tags: python, recursion, tkinter

I'm trying to make a  analogue clock in python using the after method, so the clock can update the time every 60 seconds, The problem lies in the 'def clock(self)' method  but I cant seem to fix it, this is the error I am getting

'''
elif isinstance(cnfs, (type(None), str)):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in _*instancecheck*
''''

Here's my code please help:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk  # python 3
from tkinter import ttk
from time import strftime
import math
class Tkinter(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, SecondPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.winfo_toplevel().geometry("860x864")
        frame.configure(bg='#000000')

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.cans = Canvas(self, bg='white', height=150, width=150)
        self.cans.place(relx=0.5, y=170, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.clock()


    def clock(self):
        hour = int(strftime('%H'))
        min = int(strftime('%M'))

        hangle = hour * 30
        mainangle = hangle + (min / 60 * 30)
        mangle = 90 - mainangle
        rad = mangle * (math.pi / 180)
        xlength = 75 * math.cos(rad)
        ylength = 75 * math.sin(rad)
        x = 75 + xlength
        y = 75 - ylength
        self.cans.create_line(75, 75, x, y, fill='red')
        self.after(60000, self.clock())


class SecondPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

app = Tkinter()
app.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `clock` never returns: you are *calling* `clock` recursively in order to get the argument for `self.after`.

You simply want to pass `self.clock` to `after`, so that it *can* be called in 60 seconds.

```
    self.after(60000, self.clock)
```

Comment: it was the brackets